# facebook using quickblox sdk instead of facebook-ios-sdk

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, facebook, quickblox

Is it possible to integrate facebook in my app using quickblox sdk instead of facebook-ios-sdk ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't have to use the facebook sdk, it's just better to do so because they made the sdk, it's stable, it works... why recreate the wheel but, by all means, if you only want to do something simple then go for it.

Answer (score 5):

Sure, you can.

1. Download latest version of QuickBlox iOS SDK
   http://quickblox.com/developers/IOS  (1.2.0)
2. Make query

   `[QBUsers logInWithSocialProvider:@"facebook" delegate:self];`
3. Enter you login & pass into webform
4. Catch result

> // QuickBlox queries delegate
>
> -(void)completedWithResult:(Result *)result{
>
> ```
>     // success result
>     if(result.success){
>
>             // User Login
>             if([result isKindOfClass:QBUUserLogInResult.class]){
>                 QBUUserLogInResult *res = (QBUUserLogInResult *)result;
>
>                 // Here is your Facebook access token
>                 NSString *fbAccessToken = res.socialProviderToken;
>                 NSDate *fbAccessTokenEpiresAt = res.socialProviderTokenExpiresAt
>
>                 // Make query to Facebook Graph API with your access token
>                 // ...
>
>         }else{
>             NSLog(@"Errors=%@", result.errors); 
>         }
>     }
> ```

Also, You can see at ChattAR https://github.com/QuickBlox/ChattAR-ios src - we made some queries to Facebook Graph API without Facebook-ios-sdk

p.s. could you use 'quickblox' tag in QuickBlox related questions, thx.